# Update Symfony translation files with nested keywords

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-translator

Symfony has support for nested keyword in translation files, for example:

```
symfony:
    is:
        great: Symfony is great
        amazing: Symfony is amazing
    has:
        bundles: Symfony has bundles
```

So now I can use this:

```
{% trans from 'domain' %}symfony.is.great{% endtrans %}
```

or this:

```
{% trans from 'domain' %}symfony.is.amazing{% endtrans %}
```

and everything works properly, as the official documentation says.

But, when I call command for update translation files, everything nested keywords will be converted to this:

```
symfony.is.great: Symfony is great
symfony.is.amazing: Symfony is amazing
symfony.has.bundles: Symfony has bundles
```

I need nested keywords to be preserved and properly generated. So if I define in template keyword `symfony.is.great` and `symfony.is.amazing` and call command `php bin/console translation:update --force en`, I need files with nested keywords as I mentioned above in the first example.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible with the `--as-tree` flag.

So you can use `php bin/console translation:update --force --format=yaml --as-tree=3 en`.
The '3' defines the level where to switch back to inline yaml.

Comment: Hmm, the console says: "The --as-tree option does not exist." I didn't find anything about this option. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: oh my fault. I've overread the Symfony4 Tag. This option was merged to version 5.2 at PR 38393 [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/38393)